# Sequelize: Adding a day to the date doesn't work

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql, sequelize-cli

I have a column `updatedAt` in my table `User` which is of `Date` type, it stores date along with time. I want to query using only date and not datetime. I am using sequelize `Sequelize.Op.gt` and `Sequelize.Op.lt` operators to get `Users` updated on that exact date regardless of time by adding `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`. But the date is not incrementing one day. When I try to subtract, it is working flawlessly. I could add one day only after using getTime() method.

I'm confused as to why it works when subtracting without using `getTime()` but doesn't work when adding. Could anyone explain?

**TL;DR**

This **works:**

```
[Sequelize.Op.gt]: new Date(new Date(updatedAt) - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
//updateAt: 2018-11-27
//output: 2018-11-26
```

This **doesn't** work:

```
[Sequelize.Op.gt]: new Date(new Date(updatedAt) + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
//updateAt: 2018-11-27
//output: 2018-11-27
```

And this **works:**

```
[Sequelize.Op.lt]: new Date(new Date(updatedAt).getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
//updateAt: 2018-11-27
//output: 2018-11-28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see your 2nd case step by step
1. `new Date(new Date(updatedAt) + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`
2. `new Date(new Date(updatedAt) + 86400000)`
3. `new Date('Tue Nov 27 2018 17:34:48 GMT+0800 (Some Region)86400000')`
and Date parser ignored '86400000' part of string from input.
4. `new Date('Tue Nov 27 2018 17:34:48 GMT+0800 (Some Region)')`
Now your input is not modified. Javascript doesn't know are you doing string add or number add. This is your confusing point. On other case integer addition and subtraction operators done properly

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed the string and int concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

```
sequelize.fn("DATEADD", sequelize.literal("DAY"), 4, sequelize.col('Your Date')) // 4 number of days adding
```

If want to find the difference including this added date from current date

```
sequelize.fn('DATEDIFF', sequelize.literal("DAY"), sequelize.fn("DATEADD", sequelize.literal("DAY"), 4, sequelize.col('Your Date')), sequelize.fn("GETDATE")
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATEADD(DAY, 1, `schedule_in`), `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updated_at` DAT' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be this complicated. The following will add a day to the given date:

```
const mydate = new Date("2024-01-01") 
const computedDate = +new Date(mydate) + 24*60*60*1000;
console.log(mydate, new Date(computedDate));
```

The magic is to use "+" before "new Date()" while constructing the Date object. This will return the number of milliseconds. Just add a days worth of milliseconds and you get the date advanced to 1 day.